# Glob pattern to match all files that do not start with prefix

Tags: python, linux, glob

I want to use glob pattern to match all the files in `src/` folder that do not start with prefix of two uppercase letters followed by a dot.

The glob should match the following files

```
foo.txt
foo-bar.txt
foo.bar.baz.txt
fo.txt
```

But it should not match the following files:

```
AB.foo.txt
AB.foo-bar.txt
XY.foo.bar.baz.txt
FO.fo.txt
```

The prefix will always be two uppercase letters (A to Z) followed by a dot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`glob()` can mostly do what you're looking for, but with some limitations.

You can do this:

```
glob.glob("src/[!A-Z][!A-Z][!.]*")
```

which would exclude any files that start with two uppercase letter followed by a dot. However, this particular syntax will also exclude any files with less than 3 characters in the filename. Globbing is similar to shell filename globbing syntax, and in a shell what you're looking for is more often accomplished with `find` or `grep`.

If `glob()` isn't flexible enough, you'd have to glob all files and pattern match on your own.

Comment: This would also exclude any file that contain '.' in the middle, 'foo.bar.baz.txt' world not be included in this rule.

Comment: It won't be excluded - globbing starts from the beginning of the filename. It's not a regular expression. Tested: ```glob.glob("src/[!A-Z][!A-Z][!.]*")``` returns ```['src/foo.bar.baz.txt']```.

Comment: This would exclude `Aa.p`, which is not intended.

Comment: @Philippe: hmm, you're right. I'm looking at ways to address that but I may just need to delete this answer. This probably can only be done by using ```glob``` or ```listdir``` and explicitly pattern-matching the result.

Answer (score 0):

How about the below (using [listdir](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir))

```
from os import listdir

file_list = [f for f in listdir('./src') if not (f[0].isupper() and f[1].isupper() and f[2] == '.')]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution also use listdir but use regular expression to fetch what we need.

```py
from os import listdir
import re

# Fetch any file not match Captial head kind. If non-text file exist in the directory, it might fetch it either.
file_list = [f for f in listdir('./src') if not re.match(r'[A-Z][A-Z]\..*', f)]

# Fetch any file not match Captial head kind. Fetch txt only
file_list = [f for f in listdir('./src') if not re.match(r'[A-Z][A-Z]\..*', f) and re.match(r'.*txt', f)]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look in glob.py, you can see it's using [`fnmatch.filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fnmatch.html) to filter the paths.
`fnmatch.filter` uses `fnmatch.translate` to form a regex from the pattern.
Therefore, `glob.glob("[!A-Z][!A-Z]*")` can be used (will be translated to the following regex: `'(?s:[^A-Z][^A-Z].*)\\Z'`.

Note that this will ignore anything that contains an uppercase letter in the first two indexes. The function `translate` is defined like this:

```
def translate(pat):
"""Translate a shell PATTERN to a regular expression.

There is no way to quote meta-characters.
"""
```

so i believe there is no way to include a more complicated regex expression.